# Challenges with importing - import org.knowm.xchart.*

Tags: java, xcharts

i am trying to find the two imports below.  I am using Eclipse.  Any ideas where I can find these imports?

```
     import org.knowm.xchart.*;

     import org.knowm.xchart.style.markers.SeriesMarkers;
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to download them first, since they are not part of JDK, for importing there is multiple option: 1. import it as a jar, 2. use some build tool: maven, gradle

Comment: try http://knowm.org/  - eventually the open source link there

Comment: Thank you ……. I have loaded two executables to my workstation including xchart -3.6.1...…..sorry for the dumb question but never imported a jar file.....can I do this direct from eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You mean to find the lib name contains "org.knowm.xchart"?

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.knowm.xchart